# Read results from a text file and write top5 with highest number

Tags: c#, text-files

I am creating a high score top5 list and i have no clue how to sort the data from the text file and write out the top5 with the highest int. Right now i have a program that writes the results to the text file highscore.txt.

I want it to look something like this.

```
Highscore
1. 500pts
2. 450pts
3. 400pts
4. 350pts
5. 300pts
```

Comment: Well, at least provide a couple of lines of your highscore.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a real database instead, for example the free [Sql-Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062).

If you really want to use a text-file, you could use this approach:

```
IEnumerable<string> top5HighScore = File.ReadLines("highscore.txt")
    .Select(line => int.Parse(line))
    .OrderByDescending(score => score)
    .Take(5)
    .Select((score, index) => string.Format("{0}. {1}pts", index + 1, score));
```

Now you can for example use a `foreach` to output the strings.

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.ReadLines("highscore.txt")
    .Select(line => int.Parse(line))
    .OrderByDescending(score => score)
    .Take(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution depends on your platform constraints and the size of the text file.

The simplest solution is probably to represent each line as a class.  Read in the lines from the text file, populate a list of Score and then

```
public class Score
{
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public string Player { get; set; }
}

List<Score> top5 = (from s in allScores select s)
                   .OrderByDescending(s => s.Points)
                   .Take(5);
```

If you are on a memory constrained platform relative to the size of the text file, you can use integer counters to track the lowest high-score currently in the Top 5 and use that counter to decide whether the next high score you read in from the file should be added to a list of the 5 top high scores that you maintain manually.

Either way, you can then output the top 5 like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < top5.Count; i++)
{
    Score score top5[i];
    // e.g. Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + ". " + top5.Points); 
    // Optionally output player name / initials if that was in the text file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is by-line, or you know the byte offsets in the file, then it is fairly easy to efficiently read in the entire file, and keep track of the top 5 scores, in a very memory cheap manner.

Say you have a function that returns the next score from the file (via [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aetdk20.aspx)), then the code will look something like this (I'm assuming that scores are integers):

```
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName); // create StreamReader for the file

int maxTopScores = 5; // maximum number of scores to retrieve
List<int> topScores = new List<int>(); // create a list to store the top scores in

while (!reader.EndOfStream) // check there is still data to read (or some other check, depending on file format)
{
    int tempScore = getScore(reader); // hypothetical function that retrieves the next score (returns an int)
    for (int i = 0; i < topScores.Count; i++)
    {
        if (tempScore > topScores[i])
        {
            topScores.Insert(i, tempScore); // insert this score before the one that it is bigger than
            if (topScores.Count > maxTopScores)
                topScores.RemoveAt(topScores.Count - 1); // too many scores, remove the last (lowest)
            goto scoreAdded; // sorry about the goto, but I hate breaking through loops with state booleans
        }
    }
    // score not added yet
    if (topScores.Count < maxTopScores)
        topScores.Add(tempScore); // not enough scores, add it to the end (it's the lowest yet)

scoreAdded:
    continue; // annoyingly this is needed
}
```

This *should* give you a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of int scores, with the top score being at index 0 in `topScores`, and lower scores as you move down the List. It doesn't require much memory, and you'll have a hard time crashing it.

It just loops through he file at `fileName` inserting scores into the list if they need to be, and making sure that the list doesn't contain more than `maxTopScores` scores.